# ConvertTo-Json flattens arrays over 3 levels deep

Tags: arrays, powershell

In powershell, the following produces correct results.

```
$foo = @{}
$foo.bar = @{}
$foo.bar.buzz = @("herp","derp")
ConvertTo-Json $foo

{                                     
  "bar":  {                         
    "buzz":  [            
      "herp",  
      "derp"   
    ]            
  }                         
}
```

However if I add one more level, then the array "buzz" is flattened into a string

```
$foo = @{}
$foo.bar = @{}
$foo.bar.buzz = @{}
$foo.bar.buzz.bazz = @("herp","derp")
ConvertTo-Json $foo

{
  "bar":  {
    "buzz":  {
      "bazz": "herp derp"
    }
  }
}
```

Why does powershell flatten Arrays into strings?
This issue feels similar to the following SO questions, but none of the purposed solutions solves it.

[why-does-powershell-silently-convert-a-string-array-with-one-item-to-a-string](http://why-does-powershell-silently-convert-a-string-array-with-one-item-to-a-string)

[what-determines-whether-the-powershell-pipeline-will-unroll-a-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827862/what-determines-whether-the-powershell-pipeline-will-unroll-a-collection)

Comment: This question was nice to have as the duplicates title didn't describe it well enough.  This one has a much better title.

Answer (score 3):

From [ConvertTo-Json documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> -Depth
>
> Specifies how many levels of contained objects are included in the
>   JSON representation. The default value is 2.

Adding `-Depth 9` option to `ConvertTo-Json` fixes the issue

```
ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9 $foo
```

Also, there is a difference between `ConvertTo-Json $foo` and `$foo | ConvertTo-Json`. Use `ConvertTo-Json $foo` whenever possible.

[convertto-json-an-array-with-a-single-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662967/convertto-json-an-array-with-a-single-item)