# Powershell Nested Json doesn't look like a Json

Tags: json, powershell

I am currently trying to prepare a JSON body for an API call, which should look something like this

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Authorization: Bearer ***API*KEY***' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/alert -d '{
  "title": "Other alert",
  "description": "alert description",
  "type": "external",
  "source": "instance1",
  "sourceRef": "alert-ref",
  "severity": 3,
  "tlp": 3,
  "artifacts": [
    { "dataType": "ip", "data": "127.0.0.1", "message": "localhost" },
    { "dataType": "domain", "data": "thehive-project.org", "tags": ["home", "TheHive"] },
  ],
  "caseTemplate": "external-alert"
}'
```

The problem however is that my json body which I create with powershell has weird characters and don't see where the problem is. This is my JSON Body

```
{
    "tlp":  1,
    "source":  "Test",
    "title":  "Test Alert1",
    "artifacts":  "{\r\n    \"dataType\":  \"ip\",\r\n    \"data\":  \"127.0.0.1\"\r\n}",
    "type":  "external",
    "sourceRef":  "1",
    "description":  "Test",
    "severity":  1
}
```

I create this JSON body as follows. I have already tried CustomObjects and Hashtables, but always get the same output

```
$body = @{
            title = "$title"
            description = "$Alert_Description"
            type ="external"
            source ="$Source"
            sourceRef ="$SourceRef"
            severity = $Severity
            tlp = $tlp
            $artifacts = [PSCustomObject]@{
            dataType=ip
            data=127.0.0.1}  
        }| ConvertTo-Json
        $JsonBody = $body | ConvertTo-Json
```

Can somebody give me a hint? I have no clue anymore

Comment: Why are you converting to json twice? `$body` will already be JSON strings.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I thought maybe a nested Json would help.. but that wasn't the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, **fix your hashtable** so that it creates the intended JSON representation, and only apply [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) *once*:

```
$body = [ordered] @{
  title       = $title
  description = $Alert_Description
  type        = 'external'
  source      = $Source
  sourceRef   = $SourceRef
  severity    = $Severity
  tlp         = $tlp
  artifacts   = , [pscustomobject] @{
    dataType = 'ip'
    data     = '127.0.0.1'
  }  
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

- Variables don't need enclosing in `"..."` unless you explicitly want to convert their values to strings.
- Literal textual information such as `ip` *does* require quoting (`'...'`, i.e. a verbatim string literal, is best).
- The `artifacts` property is an *array* in your sample JSON, so the unary form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-) is used to wrap the `[pscustomobject]` instance in a single-element array.

  - If you have *multiple* objects, place `,` *between* them; if the array was constructed previously and stored in a variable named, say, `$arr`, use `artifacts = $arr`.
- Use of `[ordered]`, i.e. the creation of an *ordered* hashtable isn't strictly necessary, but makes it easier to compare the resulting JSON representation to the input hashtable.
- Generally keep in mind that explicit use of a `-Depth` argument with `ConvertTo-Json` is *situationally* required in order to ensure that properties aren't truncated - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375) for more information. However, with the hashtable in your question this happens *not* to be a problem.

---

Second, since you're sending the json to an *external program*, `curl` (note that in *Windows PowerShell* you'd have to use `curl.exe` in order to bypass the built-in `curl` alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`, an **additional escaping step is - unfortunately - required up to at least v7.1** - though that may change in v7.2: The **`"` instances embedded in the value of `$body` must manually be escaped as `\"`**, due to a long-standing bug in PowerShell:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Authorization: Bearer ***API*KEY***' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' `
  http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/alert -d ($body -replace '([\\]*)"', '$1$1\"')
```

Note: With your particular sample JSON, `-replace '"', '\"'` would do.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375) for more information.

Comment: The main problem was the "" around the variables, I didn't know that this creates some weird characters..

But I'm a bit confused about the artifacts part. I've tried to add two abjects to the artifacts properties like that, but it didn't work
$collection = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
 $collection.Add([pscustomobject] @{dataType = 'username'
       data = $Username})
 $collection.Add([pscustomobject] @{dataType = 'username'
       data = $Username})
 
artifacts = $collection.ForEach($_)

Comment: @StefanRöthlisberger: Enclosing a variable reference in `"..."` in essence calls `.ToString()` on the variable, using the invariant culture, and has special handling for arrays, which stringify as a space-separated list of their (stringified) elements (try `"$(1,2,3)"`.  As for the `artifacts` part: `artifacts = $collection`

Answer (score 1):

Slap a "-Depth 50" on your ConvertTo-Json, that should solve your issue.

Like here: [ConvertTo-Json flattens arrays over 3 levels deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448161/convertto-json-flattens-arrays-over-3-levels-deep)

Comment: While this is a good tip in general, `-Depth` is not required to get a full JSON representation of the hashtable in the question (it isn't nested deeply enough to be a problem), whereas there are other, obvious problems with the code.