# Adding a timestamp in a JSON body

Tags: json, rest, powershell, api, pscustomobject

I am quite new to powershell and not used to it yet. I am trying to remote some of my servers in RealTime. 
For that I use a RestAPI that send me data on a JSON format (that Powershell automatically convert to a PSCustomObject).

The thing is that there is no field timestamp in my JSON/data API so I have had to add it. Unfortunately, JSON tools in powershell seems limited and I was not able to add it directly. I had to create a new PSCustomObject called timestamp and combine it with my data from the API.

Unfortunetaly the data then is not parsed correctly.
I tring going through a string, an array of string, a hashtable. It was worst.
Finally I downloaded a JSON.NET Framework which I am trying to work with now...

So here is the main code part :

```
Function Combine-Objects { 
    Param (
        [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]$Object1, 
        [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]$Object2
    )

    $arguments = [Pscustomobject]@() 
    foreach ( $Property in $Object1.psobject.Properties){
        $arguments += @{$Property.Name = $Property.value}  
    }

    foreach ( $Property in $Object2.psobject.Properties){
        $arguments += @{ $Property.Name= $Property.value}         
    }

    $Object3 = [Pscustomobject]$arguments

    return $Object3
    }

while (1) 
{
    $startpoint = "REST API URL"
    $endpoint = "POWER BI API URL"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $startpoint 
    $timestamp=get-date -format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ 
    $response2 = [PsCustomObject]@{"timestamp"=$timestamp}
    $response3 = Combine-Objects -Object1 $response -Object2 $response2
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($response3))
}
```

Before combnining PSCustomObject I have :

```
    total     : 8589463552
    available : 5146566656
    percent   : 40,1
    used      : 3442896896
    free      : 5146566656
```

which gave me a correct JSON after converting it

```
    [
        {
            "total":  8589463552,
            "available":  5146566656,
            "percent":  40.1,
            "used":  3442896896,
            "free":  5146566656
        }
    ]
```

While after combining and adding a timestamp I have :

```
    Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                           
    ----                           -----                                                                                                                                                           
    total                          8589463552                                                                                                                                                      
    available                      5146566656                                                                                                                                                      
    percent                        40,1                                                                                                                                                            
    used                           3442896896                                                                                                                                                      
    free                           5146566656                                                                                                                                                      
    timestamp                      2019-10-09T22:17:18.734Z
```

Which gave me after conversion :

```
    [
        {
            "total":  8589463552
        },
        {
            "available":  5146566656
        },
        {
            "percent":  40.1
        },
        {
            "used":  3442896896
        },
        {
            "free":  5146566656
        },
        {
            "timestamp":  "2019-10-09T22:17:18.734Z"
        }
    ]
```

While all I wanted was simply :

```
    [
     {
      "total" :98.6,
      "available" :98.6,
      "percent" :98.6,
      "used" :98.6,
      "free" :98.6,
      "timestamp" :"2019-10-11T09:21:04.981Z"
     }
    ]
```

Comment: `$arguments = [Pscustomobject]@()` -> `$arguments = @{}` inside your `Combine-Objects` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking at this the wrong way. Why not simply add the `NoteProperty` containing the `DateTime string` to the `PSCustomObject` and then convert it back to the `json` format?

Something like this would be enough:

```
$json = @"
 [
    {
         "total":  8589463552,
         "available":  5146566656,
         "percent":  40.1,
         "used":  3442896896,
         "free":  5146566656
     }
  ]
"@
```

```
$jsonConverted = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
    
$params = @{
   NotePropertyName  = 'timestamp'
   NotePropertyValue = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff')
}
$jsonConverted | Add-Member @params
    
$newJson = $jsonConverted | ConvertTo-Json  
$newJson
```

This will result in the `json` object you're looking for:

```json
{
    "total":  8589463552,
    "available":  5146566656,
    "percent":  40.1,
    "used":  3442896896,
    "free":  5146566656,
    "timestamp":  "2019-10-11T13:33:05.673"
}
```

Comment: Hi Darklite1, Thank you very much !
I indeed was thinking about the add-member function, but I was confused with the types. So I believe a JSON is treated by default as a PSCustomObject by Powershell.

Despite I still have an issue :
 `{
    "total":  8589463552,
    ...
    "timestamp":  "2019-10-11T13:33:05.673"
}`

instead of

`[
     {
      "total" :98.6,
       ...
      "timestamp" :"2019-10-11T09:21:04.981Z"
     }]`

Comment: It worked, thanks man ! I just added something like  `$output = "['n " + $outputTEMP + "'n]"`,to get the right format

Comment: Yw :) To achieve the `array` format of the `json` object you need to use `$NewJson = ConvertTo-Json @($JsonConverted)` instead of `$NewJson = $JsonConverted | ConvertTo-Json`. Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662967/convertto-json-an-array-with-a-single-item).

Comment: Perfect, definetly cleaner than my workaround. Nice !

Comment: The symbols `[` .. `]` indicate in `json` formatting that it is an `array`, meaning a collection of objects or a group of objects. An `array` in PowerShell is indicated as `@(` .. `)`. Glad I could be of help to you. Keep exploring, the more you play with it the better you'll get :)

Comment: Thanks it makes a lot of sense with the explanations :)