# Create a Single-Element Json Array Object Using PowerShell

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I have a powershell 5.1 script that I've created that imports a csv file, manipulates some of the data, then converts the object of data to json format using the ConvertTo-Json cmdlet at the end of the script. The problem that I'm running into; in one of my fields I need to create a single array for the object property with brackets. So I need the object to be like:

```
"PersonGroups":[
              {
                "Name":"test Name",
                "Id": 3433
              }
            ]
```

Here is the call to the function:

```
 $_.PersonGroups = Set-DataHash -InputObject $_
```

Below is my code that I have:

```
function Set-DataHash{
param(
    [psobject] $InputObject
)

$customObject = [psobject]@{
   Name = "Test"
   Id = 78888
}

$customArray = @($customObject)

return $customArray
```

}

Of course if I have more than one object in the array it works fine; but since it's only one object ConvertTo-Json makes it a single object. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: how are you calling `convertto-json`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ConvertTo-JSON an array with a single item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662967/convertto-json-an-array-with-a-single-item)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: JSON is ultimately incidental to this question, which is at heart about how to output (return) a collection _as a whole_ from a _function_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
 $_.PersonGroups = @(Set-DataHash -InputObject $_)
```

You don't need the "return".

Comment: Greatly, appreciate the help. I agree that the return is not needed but I hate that VS code gives me a warning informing me that the variable has been assigned but not used. It's pretty much an insanity check for me or am I thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: You don't have to assign any variables either.  Just put a [pscustomobject] expression by itself.

Answer (score 2):

**[js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62488881/45375) shows how to solve the problem on the *caller*'s side**, using `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), around your `Set-DataHash` function call to ensure that the return value is an *array*.

**If you want to solve the problem *from within your function*, you must ensure that the array being output (returned) is output *as a whole*, as a *single object***, which can be achieved with an **auxiliary single-element wrapper array** created with the **unary form of **`,`** the [array constructor ("comma") operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-)**:

```
function Set-DataHash {
  param(
    [psobject] $InputObject
  )
  
  $customObject = [psobject] @{
    Name = "Test"
    Id   = 78888
  }
  
  # Wrap $customObject in an array with @(...), 
  # then *additionally* wrap this array in an *auxiliary* single-element array,
  # via `,` (array-construction operator).
  # Outputting this aux. array causes *it* to be enumerated, which therefore
  # outputs its only element as-is: the *original* array - see explanation below.
  # Note: I've omitted `return`, which is always optional.
  , @($customObject)
  
}
```

**Explanation**:

**By default - irrespective of whether you use `return` or *implicit* output in  a function or script - outputting a collection (including arrays) causes its elements to be *enumerated* (aka *streamed*, unwrapped or unrolled)**; that is, the elements are output *one by one* to the (invisible, in this case) *pipeline* through which the caller receives the output.

- **In the case of a *single*-element collection, the nature of the pipeline is such that the caller receives just that single element itself - the collection wrapper is lost.**
- In the case of a *multi*-element collection, the specific original collection is lost too, and the enumerated elements are automatically collected in an `[object[]]` *array*).

Therefore, wrapping a collection that you want to output *as a whole*, as a *single object* requires the aux. single-element wrapper array technique shown above; **a less efficient alternative is to use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output) with the `-NoEnumerate` switch**, which too prevents enumeration of a collection passed to it as an argument (not via the pipeline).

---

Note:

- ***In general*, in functions/scripts intended to be called directly by others, it is better *not* to output collections as a whole**, so as not to confound the general expectation of *streaming (enumerating) behavior* in the pipeline; in the streaming case, **it is the *caller* that must ensure that the collected output is an array, via `@(...)`**, as shown in js2010's answer; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375) for background information.
- Conversely, however, outputting collections as a whole is *faster* and allows you to output a *specific collection type*.