# Cannot add single element array to hashtable in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

In PS 5.1 I wrote this little func to ensure that the result of Processor will always be an array but for some strange reason it does not work. Do you know why?

```
function ConvertTo-Array($result) {
   [bool]$isArray = ($result.getType() | Select-Object basetype).toString() -eq "System.Array"

   if ($isArray -eq $false) {
      return  @($result)
   }
   return $result
}

$table = @{
   "Processor" = ConvertTo-Array(Get-wmiobject Win32_Processor | Select-Object -Property Name, Number*);
}

$machinedata = @{
   "Machine Info" = $table;
}

write-output (ConvertTo-Json $machinedata -Depth 3)
```

If I do this instead it works

```
...
"Processor" = @(Get-wmiobject Win32_Processor | Select-Object -Property Name, Number*);
...
```

Comment: Instead of `return @($result)`, use `Write-Output $result -NoEnumerate`. You are fighting PowerShell's want to unroll array outputs.

Comment: `@()`'s entire purpose is to ensure that an expression evaluates to an array, I would definitely stick with it rather than reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: In short: output from functions is also subject to _enumeration_ of collections - whether or not you use `return`. While you can prevent this enumeration from within the function with `Write-Output -NoEnumerate <value>` or, preferably, `, <value>`, using `@(...)` on the _caller_'s side is the more PowerShell-idiomatic solution - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62489498/45375).

Comment: My problem is that if I do ```@()``` without the method then I may end up with a ([[]]) nested array which I don't want either. I'll probably have to solve this at the other side with a custom deserializer.