# Using $_ export with invoke-command

Tags: powershell

Can someone tell me why this invoke-command is not exporting all the variables?

```
icm -computername Server1 -scriptblock {
  $A=$env:username;$B=hostname;$C=$env:userdomain;echo $A,$B,$C
} | 
  % {$_ | out-file "c:\temp\$($_.pscomputername).txt"}
```

The text file only contains "$C=$env:userdomain" variable. How can i export $A,$B,$C variables to the text file while keeping the $_.pscomputername as the name of the exported file?

thank you

Comment: Add `-Append` to `Out-File` (or remove `%{ $_ | ... }` and just pipe directly into `Out-File`)

Comment: $env:username will be the same username as the caller of invoke-command; $env:hostname (u missed the $env) will be the same as pscomputername... I would build a object and use return to give the information back to the caller

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that *each individual object* output by `icm` (`Invoke-Command`) causes the output file passed to `Out-File` in the `%` (`ForEach-Object`) script block to be rewritten, so that you end up with only the *last* one in the file.

[Toni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19895159/toni) makes good points about the values you're returning from your remote script block, and about collecting the information in a *single object*, which solves your problem.

Applying the same idea to the multiple values you're trying to return, you can return them *as a single array, as a whole*, so that you only have *one* object to write, which contains all the information.

To that end, you not only must construct an array, but also prevent its *enumeration* on output, which is most easily done by using the unary form of `,` to create an aux. wrapper array (alternatively, use `Write-Output -NoEnumerate`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62489498/45375) for more information).

```
icm -computername Server1 -scriptblock {
  # Return the values as a single array, wrapped in 
  # in a aux. array to prevent enumeration.
  , ($env:username, (hostname), $env:userdomain)
} | 
  % { 
    # Now each targeted computer returns only *one* object.
    $_ | out-file "c:\temp\$($_.pscomputername).txt"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more typical usage.  Instead of format-table, you can pipe to export-csv.  It runs in parallel on both computers.

```
icm -computername com001,com002 -scriptblock {
  [pscustomobject]@{Username=$env:username;
                    Hostname=hostname;
                  Userdomain=$env:userdomain}
} | format-table


Username   Hostname Userdomain PSComputerName RunspaceId
--------   -------- ---------- -------------- ----------
js-adm     COM001   AD         com001         2d660bb5-761c-4e79-9e4f-c3b98f5f8c61
js-adm     COM002   AD         com002         7544a8ff-e419-49c2-9fc3-2a92f50c1424
```