# PowerShell - array of type HashSet

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashset

I am trying to create an array of HashSets but it always comes out as simply a HashSet. Here is a test script I made:

```
$arrHashSets = @();

$hs = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string];
$hs2 = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string];

$hs.Add("A");
$hs.Add("B");
$hs.Add("C");

$hs2.Add("A");
$hs2.Add("B");
$hs2.Add("C");

$arrHashSets += $hs;
$arrHashSets += $hs2;
```

Expected result:

```
$arrHashSets = [
    {"A", "B", "C"},
    {"A", "B", "C"}
]
```

Actual result:

```
$arrHashSets = {"A", "B", "C"}
```

I tried doing it a few different ways but `$arrHashSets` always comes out as simply a HashSet rather than an array of type HashSet. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
$arrHashSets += $hs
$arrHashSets += $hs2
```

with:

```
$arrHashSets = $hs, $hs2
```

If you do need to build up an array(-like data structure) *iteratively*:

```
$lstHashSets = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
foreach ($thisHs in $hs, $hs2) {
  $lstHashSets.Add($thisHs)
}
```

<sup>Note: For simplicity the generic list is `[object]`-typed here, but you could more strictly type it as `[System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]]`.</sup>

However, creating an array / list *explicitly* isn't strictly needed, given that you can use a statement such as [`foreach` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) *as an expression* whose multiple outputs PowerShell *implicitly* captures in an array for you:

```
$arrHashSets = @(
  foreach ($thisHs in $hs, $hs2) {
    , $thisHs
  }
)
```

Note:

- `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) is necessary to ensure that an array is also constructed in the event that the `foreach` loop happens to output only a *single* object.
- The unary form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-) is used to in effect ensure that each hash set is output *as a whole*. By default, PowerShell would *enumerate* the hash set's entries, i.e. output them *one by one* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62489498/45375) for more information.

---

As for **what you tried**:

**Using `+=` to "extend" an array**:

- is **generally to be avoided** due to its inefficiency: a *new* array must be created behind the scenes every time - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375).
- "adds" to the existing array by appending the *elements* of the RHS, if it is an *enumerable*, rather than appending the RHS *as a whole*. Thus, the hash set is *enumerated* and its elements become direct elements of the resulting, flat array.

Comment: Thanks mklement0! I found that your first suggestion didn't make a difference, but using a List instead of an array worked, along with using `.Add()` instead of `+=`.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SendETHToThisAddress, though the first suggestion should work as well; try this simplified command: `$arr = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] ('A', 'B', 'C'), [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] ('D', 'E', 'F')`

Comment: @SendETHToThisAddress, I corrected a problem in my answer where I inadvertently used `$hs` as the _iteration_ variable as well.