# How to pipe results into output array

Tags: powershell, jagged-arrays, select-string

After playing around with some powershell script for a while i was wondering if there is a version of this without using c#. It feels like i am missing some information on how to pipe things properly.

```
$packages = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\A\Downloads" -Filter "*.nupkg" |
    %{ $_.Name } 
    # Select-String -Pattern "(?<packageId>[^\d]+)\.(?<version>[\w\d\.-]+)(?=.nupkg)" |
    # %{ @($_.Matches[0].Groups["packageId"].Value, $_.Matches[0].Groups["version"].Value) } 

         
foreach ($package in $packages){
    
    $match = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($package, "(?<packageId>[^\d]+)\.(?<version>[\w\d\.-]+)(?=.nupkg)")
    Write-Host "$($match.Groups["packageId"].Value) - $($match.Groups["version"].Value)"  
}
```

Originally i tried to do this with powershell only and thought that with @(1,2,3) you could create an array.

I ended up bypassing the issue by doing the regex with c# instead of powershell, which works, but i am curious how this would have been done with powershell only.

While there are 4 packages, doing just the powershell version produced 8 lines. So accessing my data like $packages[0][0] to get a package id never worked because the 8 lines were strings while i expected 4 arrays to be returned

Comment: What do you mean "without using C#"? There's not a single line of C# in your question...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match is c# functionality, not powershell

Comment: It really isn't "C# functionality", it's _shared_ functionality :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminology note re *without using c#*:  You mean without direct use of *.NET APIs*. By contrast, C# is just another .NET-based language that can make use of such APIs, just like PowerShell itself.

Note:

- The next section answers the following question: How can I avoid direct calls to .NET APIs for my regex-matching code in favor of using PowerShell-native commands (operators, automatic variables)?
- See the bottom section for the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) solution that was your true objective; the **tl;dr** is:

  ```bash
  # Note the `, `, which ensures that the array is output *as a single object*
  %{ , @($_.Matches[0].Groups["packageId"].Value, $_.Matches[0].Groups["version"].Value) }
  ```

---

The **PowerShell-native (near-)equivalent of your code** is (note tha the assumption is that `$package` contains the *content* of the input file):

```bash
# Caveat: -match is case-INSENSITIVE; use -cmatch for case-sensitive matching.
if ($package -match '(?<packageId>[^\d]+)\.(?<version>[\w\d\.-]+)(?=.nupkg)') {
  "$($Matches['packageId']) - $($Matches['Version'])"  
}
```

- **`-match`**, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), is the equivalent of [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match) (which you can shorten to `[regex]::Match()`) in that it **only looks for (at most) *one* match**.

  - Caveat re case-sensitivity: **`-match`** (and its rarely used alias `-imatch`) **is case-*insensitive* by default**, as all PowerShell operators are; for case-sensitive matching, use the `c`-prefixed variant, `-cmatch`.
  - By contrast, **.NET APIs are case-*sensitive* by default**; you'd have to pass the `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase` flag to `[regex]::Match()` for case-insensitive matching (you may use `'IgnoreCase'`, which PowerShell auto-converts for you).
  - As of PowerShell 7.2.x, **there is *no* operator that is the equivalent of the related return-ALL-matches .NET API, [`[regex]::Matches()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches)**.  See [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) for a **green-lit but yet-to-be-implemented proposal** to introduce one, named **`-matchall`**.
- However, instead of directly returning an *object* describing what was (or wasn't) matched, **`-match` returns a *Boolean***, i.e. `$true` or `$false`, to indicate whether matching succeeded.
- **Only if `-match` returns `$true` does information about a match become available, namely via the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches)**, which is a [hashtable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) reflecting the matching parts of the input string: entry `0` is always the full match, with optional additional entries reflecting what any capture groups (`(...)`) captured, either by *index*, if they're *anonymous* (starting with `1`) or, as in your case, for *named* capture groups (`(?<name>...)`) by *name*.

  - Syntax note: Given that PowerShell allows use of dot notation (property-access syntax) even with hashtables, the above command could have used `$Matches.packageId` instead of `$Matches['packageId']`, for instance, which also works with the *numeric* (index-based) entries, e.g., `$Matches.0` instead of `$Matches[0]`
  - Caveat: If an *array* (enumerable) is used as the LHS operand, `-match`' behavior changes:

    - `$Matches` is *not* populated.
    - *filtering* is performed; that is, instead of returning a Boolean indicating whether matching succeeded, the *subarray of matching input strings* is returned.
  - Note that **the `$Matches` hashtable only provides the matched *strings*, not also metadata such as index and length**, as found in `[regex]::Match()`'s return object, which is of type [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match).

---

**[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) solution**:

```bash
$packages | 
  Select-String '(?<packageId>[^\d]+)\.(?<version>[\w\d\.-]+)(?=.nupkg)' |
  ForEach-Object {
    "$($_.Matches[0].Groups['packageId'].Value) - $($_.Matches[0].Groups['version'].Value)"
  }
```

- `Select-String` outputs [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances, whose `.Matches` collection contains one or more [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) instances, i.e. instances of the same type as returned by `[regex]::Match()`

  - Unless `-AllMatches` is also passed, `.Matches` only ever has *one* entry, hence the use of `[0]` to target that entry above.

As you can see, working with `Select-Object`'s output objects requires you to ultimately work with the same .NET type as when you call `[regex]::Match()` directly.
However, no *method calls* are required, and discovering the properties of the output objects is made easy in PowerShell via the [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) cmdlet.

---

If you want to **capture the matches in a jagged *array***:

```bash
$capturedStrings = @(
  $packages | 
    Select-String '(?<packageId>[^\d]+)\.(?<version>[\w\d\.-]+)(?=.nupkg)' |
    ForEach-Object {
      # Output an array of all capture-group matches, 
      # *as a single object* (note the `, `) 
      , $_.Matches[0].Groups.Where({ $_.Name -ne '0' }).Value 
    }
)
```

This returns an array of arrays, each element of which is the array of capture-group matches for a given package, so that `$capturedStrings[0][0]` returns the `packageId` value for the first package, for instance.

Note:

- `$_.Matches[0].Groups.Where({ $_.Name -ne '0' }).Value` programmatically enumerates all capture-group matches and returns an their `.Value` property values *as an array*, using [member-access enumeration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration); note how name `'0'` must be excluded, as it represents the *whole* match.

  - With the capture groups in your specific regex, the above is equivalent to the following, as shown in a commented-out line in your question:

    ```bash
    @($_.Matches[0].Groups['packageId'].Value, $_.Matches[0].Groups['version'].Value)
    ```
- `, ...`, the unary form of the [array-construction operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), is used as a shortcut for outputting the array (symbolized by `...` here) *as a whole*, as a *single object*. By default, *enumeration* would occur and the elements would be emitted *one by one*. `, ...` is in effect a shortcut to the conceptually clearer `Write-Output -NoEnumerate ...` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62489498/45375) for an explanation of the technique.
- Additionally, `@(...)`, the [array subexpression operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) is needed in order to ensure that a jagged array (nested array) is returned even in the event that only *one* array is returned across all `$packages`.

Comment: @Dbl, I now see that I missed the _commented-out_ lines in the code snippet in your question, which indeed show that unary `, ` was the only missing part. I simply glossed over them, assuming that they weren't important, due to being commented out. Anyway, I'm glad we found a solution.